# How to diagnose service after image deployment on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I'm using the following script to deploy new image to a kubernetes cluster:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail
set -x

rootPath=".."
gcpProjectId="example123"
gcpRepoHostname="eu.gcr.io"
imageName="wordpress"
containerName="wordpress"
tagNameSuffix=$(date +%s)
tagNameSuffix="deploy-${tagNameSuffix}"
tagName="$gcpRepoHostname"/"$gcpProjectId"/"$imageName":$tagNameSuffix

echo "$GCLOUD_API_KEYFILE" | base64 --decode --ignore-garbage > ./gcloud-api-key.json
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-api-key.json
gcloud config set project "$gcpProjectId"

sudo docker build "$rootPath"/wordpress/ -t "$tagName"
sudo gcloud docker -- push "$tagName"
kubectl set image deployment/wordpress "$containerName"="$tagName"
```

Strangely this worked when I modified the `wordpress/Dockerfile` to be:

```
FROM rlesouef/alpine-nginx
```

If I change it to:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.1-fpm-alpine

COPY custom-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

I get a non responsive service - fails to connect to the external ip.

---

Heres is some debug information relating to the last change (wordpress image):

`kubectl get pods` shows the following:

```
NAME                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
wordpress-702001878-xb0b1   2/2       Running   0          8m
```

If I check the logs via `kubectl logs wordpress-702001878-xb0b1 wordpress`:

```
[07-Aug-2017 15:13:14] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
[07-Aug-2017 15:13:14] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

How can I diagnose this issue? I suppose I need to determine the exact docker image being currently run on the cluster / pods.

Comment: To compare the docker image, on the node you can run the `docker images` command and compare the image id. Troubleshoot install the busybox image and get the terminal session, try to access wordpress service using pod to make pod started with-out any  issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kubectl get pods`

Note the pod name.

Then exec into the pod:
`kubectl exec -c wordpress -it wordpress-915256023-g68cr -- bash`

I was then able to determine that the container was listening on port 9000 (by running `netstat -l`). Which made me realize this isn't HTTP server, but the PHP-FPM (so some other form of server).